# How to change the corresponding font name in JCombobox while placing the cursor or selecting the text in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am creating a text editor application in Java Swing. I am using JTextPane and I have added code to get all the system fonts and some font sizes in JComboBox.

I have entered the text - "Hello World" in jtextpane and change the font of the words "Hello" to "Arial", font size to 10 and "World" to "Calibri", font size to 12.

My expected scenario:
If I select the word "Hello" or place the cursor in the word "Hello", the font name in the font JCombobox should be changed automatically to "Arial" and font size Jcombobox should be automatically changed to 10, as same as for the word "World", the values in the Jcombobox should be changed to "Calibri" and "12". How can I achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this works, but a `CaretListener` is what I thought first. Based on the  position of the caret, or the selected text one can determine the position in the document (associated with the editor/text pane) and retrieve the document attributes at that position. The attributes will tell what the font or its size is; use them to set it in the respective combo boxes.

Comment: When I select text like "Hello world" -and- "Hello" is of size 18 and "world" is of size 24. What size is to be set in the combobox?  What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically addresses the issue how to select the combo box item corresponding to the selected text or the cursor position in text. For the example, I have chosen only the font size. The same technique can be applied to the font family also.

The example is a text editor using `JTextPane` and its document type is a `DefaultStyledDocument`. There is a `JComboBox` with a list of font sizes (16 to 50). One can select a section of text in the editor and select a font size from combo box to set the text to that font size. This is achieved using an `ItemListener` added to the `JComboBox`. The listener has code to set the editor document's attributes to the newly selected font size - to the selected text.

The editor allows multiple font sizes applied to different parts of the text as in the below picture.

[image]

The requirement was when the caret (or cursor) is placed in the text or a portion of selected text - the corresponding font size need to be set in the `JComboBox` with the font sizes. For this a `CaretListener` is added to the `JTextPane`.

This listener's logic mainly locates the caret position, gets the attributes of the document text at that position and extracts the font size attribute. This font size from this attribute is set in the font size combo box.

The example's code:

```
public class Editor2 {

    private JTextPane editor;
    private DefaultStyledDocument doc;
    private JComboBox<String> fontSizeComboBox;
    private boolean caretControlFlag;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 18;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Editor2().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        editor = new JTextPane();
        editor.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        editor.addCaretListener(new MyCaretListener());     
        JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editor);
        doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
        initDocAttrs();
        editor.setDocument(doc);

        final String [] fontSizes = {"Font Size", "16", "18", 
            "20", "24", "28", "30", "34", "40", "50"};
        fontSizeComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(fontSizes);
        fontSizeComboBox.setEditable(false);
        fontSizeComboBox.addItemListener(new FontSizeItemListener());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
        frame.add(fontSizeComboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(editorScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(editorScrollPane);
        frame.setSize(800, 400);
        frame.setLocation(300, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        editor.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private void initDocAttrs() {
        Style style = doc.addStyle("my_doc_style", null);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 18);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "SansSerif");
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), style, true);
    }

    private class FontSizeItemListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if ((e.getStateChange() != ItemEvent.SELECTED) ||
                    (fontSizeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0)) {
                return;
            }
            String fontSizeStr = (String) e.getItem();
            int newFontSize = 0;
            try {
                newFontSize = Integer.parseInt(fontSizeStr);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return;
            }
            if (caretControlFlag) {
                caretControlFlag = false;
                return;
            }
            setFontAttrs(newFontSize);
            editor.requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        private void setFontAttrs(int newFontSize) {
            SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            Style docStyle = doc.getStyle("my_doc_style");  
            int size = StyleConstants.getFontSize(docStyle);
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrs, newFontSize);
            String attrName = "mysize" + Integer.toString(newFontSize);
            attrs.addAttribute(attrName, attrName);

            int startPos = editor.getSelectionStart();
            String selectedText = editor.getSelectedText();
            if (selectedText == null || selectedText.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            int length = selectedText.length(); 
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(startPos, length, attrs, false);     
            editor.setDocument(doc);
        }
    }


    private class MyCaretListener implements CaretListener {
        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            caretControlFlag = true;
            int dot = e.getDot();
            Element ele = doc.getCharacterElement(dot);
            AttributeSet attrs = ele.getAttributes();
            String fontSizeStr = "18";
            for (Enumeration en = attrs.getAttributeNames(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                String attrName = en.nextElement().toString();
                if (attrName.contains("mysize")) {
                    fontSizeStr = attrName.substring(6);
                }
            }
            fontSizeComboBox.setSelectedItem(fontSizeStr);
            caretControlFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I will try this one.

Comment: Hi Prasad, the scenario is working fine,thanks. But, 1. the font size is not changing in the editor when we dont select any text (ie, without selecting any text am changing the font size and entering some text - the new font size is not applied for the newly entered text), 2. if I copy  any text from any other source and paste it in the editor, at that scenario the font size is not changing in font combo box according to pasted text. If you can please help me on this.

Comment: _1. the font size is not changing in the editor when we dont select any text (ie, without selecting any text am changing the font size and entering some text - the new font size is not applied for the newly entered text)_:  That is because when you place the cursor the font size is set to the whatever size exists. If you change the font size in the combo box it will still revert back to the original size. The program doesn't know your intention . This needs some work, what it is I don't know - yet.

Comment: _2. if I copy any text from any other source and paste it in the editor, at that scenario the font size is not changing in font combo box according to pasted text._ The pasted text will have the font size of the position where you are pasting it. If the font size is 30 at a position, and if you paste some text there, the newly pasted text will have the size of 30. That is the expected behavior.

Comment: _This about the item 2 question_: If you remove the caret listener I think it will work like the way you are expecting. There must be some way you have to tell the editor that you intend to do some action like editing or pasting new text, then the editor can allow you to enter the set font size (logic can be built around that). If you remove the caret listener this will work as you expect; that is the catch (or is it _catch 22!_).

Comment: _For example, you may want to try this approach_: whenever you select a new font in the combo box -and- no text is selected, you set a flag - and this indicates your intention to use that font for newly entered text at/from that position. Then the text entered at that position will have the new font size (you have build logic into the listeners). This is how you may have to try (experiment little bit, use your imagination, etc) and see how it works.

Comment: Instead of setting the combo box with the font size  whenever you place a cursor in the editor (or select some text), you can consider having a display area like a `JLabel` display the selected text's or position's font size. Just a thought.

Comment: Try searching the net using search text something like this: _java swing jtextpane font size_. There are quite a few posts and code samples (for example, [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ChangetheFontsizeofJTextPane.htm)). You may find something helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your great help Prasad, I will try with your suggestions.

Comment: Hi, sorry for asking you again, based on your suggestions, I have modified your code and found a solution, here is the code:

Comment: In the modified code, pressing Ctrl+A changing the content's different font style to the same font style, I couldn't able to post the modified code in this comment, so I have created a new page:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219470/pressing-ctrla-is-changing-the-font-in-jtextpane  , can you help me on this?

Comment: _You_ can post an _answer_ on this page itself (for your own question; it happens once in a while) and I think its good to post answers found. Anyone visiting the page in future can benefit from.it